# RegEx for dash and backtick, if included in a string, should have alphabets only at pre and post occurrence

Tags: .net, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

```
[RegularExpression("^([a-zA-Z-`])+$", ErrorMessage = "Please correct your First Name - this should not contain any special characters other than - or `.")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

I have the above regex pattern to allow users to input alphabets, dash and backtick only. However I am not able to create a pattern to only allow an alphabet to be followed by the dash or apostrophe. eg:

**valid**: sam`s, abd-cdf, dbc-dfd`s

**invalid**: sam``s, abcd--cef, dbf-`dfd, dbf`-dfd

How can I make sure that the above two special characters: dash and backtick , if included in  a string, should have alphabets only at pre and post occurrence.

Comment: `sam\`s` is both valid and invalid? =P Also, this is called backtick, not apostrophe. Apostrophe is `'`

Comment: Can the dash/apostrophe appear at the beginning or end of the string? Or only in the middle?

Comment: @Jerry yeah my mistake. I had apostrophe in my mind. cheers

Comment: @SmokeyPHP only in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you should avoid placing a dash (or hyphen) in between characters in a character class unless you want a range of characters. Since you want only backticks and hyphens, it would be better to use:

```
^[a-zA-Z`-]+$
```

Also, I don't think the capture group is necessary here.

On to the next requirement. You might want to use something like that:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[`-][a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

This is any number of letters, followed by either `` ` `` or `-` and a nother series of letters, and makes the backtick and hyphen appear only in the middle of the string.

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/wQ1tV2)

Comment: thanks mate. I am just checking this pattern with different variations. But it seems to be right for my case. Also ur answer gave me one more useful resource info regex101.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

```
^([a-zA-Z]|(?<=[a-zA-Z])[`-])+$
```

Which will match any number of either

```
[a-zA-Z]
```

or

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])[`-])
```

The second part uses a lookbehind which says that a backtick or `-` must be preceeded by one of the character class `[a-zA-Z]`

[demo](http://rubular.com/r/OTtNbsbonU)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should work for you. Let me know if you have some other conditions as well.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+((`|-)[a-zA-Z]+)*$
```